# string/integer vector - cout

Tags: c++, vector

I tried to make a program that will ask the user to input pancakes eaten by 10 people and then list them. People's names and pancakes eaten were stored in different vectors. I am getting an error when printing the values from the vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stl_vector.h>
#include <bits/stl_bvector.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> pancakes;
    vector<string> name;
    int temp_num;
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        cout << "Enter pancakes eaten by person " << x+1 << endl;
        cin >> temp_num;
        pancakes.push_back(temp_num);
        name.push_back("Person " + x);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        cout << name[x] << " ate " << pancakes[x] << " candies." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error I'm getting is "Subscripted value is not an array.".

Comment: Pretty sure `"Person " + x` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Show us the *entire* error message, please.  (Also, why are you including `<bits/stl_vector.h>` instead of the standard `<vector>`?)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add a `std::string` and an `int`, so this is not allowed

```
name.push_back("Person " + x);
```

You can, however, use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) and *then* concatenate.

```
name.push_back("Person " + std::to_string(x));
```

Also I'm not sure why you have `<bits>` includes, you should only have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

Comment: but... but... I don't like string streams :(

Comment: @Cyber `boost::lexical_cast`. And +1 if you do it using some internal boost header like the OP :P. But seriously, the code will compile even though you say *this is not allowed*, so you should explain what's happening in the OP's code.

Comment: One minor nit - `"Person "` is not a `std::string`.